# C++, destructor of a singleton class is called once again

Tags: c++, singleton

I made a simple singleton class.
While running test, I got some weired result.

Destructor is called once again.

Here is result and my code.

**Result** : I expect destructor is called 4 times, because I called `GetInstance()` 4 times. **But** Desctuructor is called **5 times**!

```
Start Test
TestClass Constructor
   TestClass Destructor
   TestClass Destructor
   TestClass Destructor
   TestClass Destructor
   TestClass Destructor
```

**singleton.h**

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H_
#define SINGLETON_H_

#include "basictype.h"

namespace common {
namespace internal {

// Usage :
// MyClass mine = common::internal::Singleton<MyClass>::GetInstace();
// mine.foo();

// This Singleton class is maybe the best one avoiding memory allocation.
// See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289
template <typename Type>
class Singleton {
 public:
  static Type& GetInstance() {
    static Type instance;
    return instance;
  }
 private:
  Singleton() {};

  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(Singleton);
};

}  // namespace internal
}  // namespace common

#endif  // SINGLETON_H_
```

**main.c**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "singleton.h"

class TestClass {
 public:
  TestClass() {
    std::cout << "TestClass Constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  ~TestClass() {
    std::cout << "   TestClass Destructor" << std::endl;
  }
};

void runSingletonTest() {
  TestClass tc = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
  TestClass tc2 = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
  TestClass tc3 = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
  TestClass tc4 = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "Start Test" << std::endl;
  runSingletonTest();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not really a singleton, right? Your constructor&destructor should be private; the instance created by the static declaration inside GetInstance should be the only one (if you follow correctly the pattern).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually have 5 instances of `TestClass` in your code.

The first one is created by

```
static Type instance;
```

using the *default constructor*. This produces the line `TestClass Constructor` in your output.

The other 4 are created by

```
TestClass tc = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
TestClass tc2 = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
TestClass tc3 = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
TestClass tc4 = common::internal::Singleton<TestClass>::GetInstance();
```

using the *copy constructor*. The copy constructor is generated by the compiler and does not output anything (That's why you see only one `TestClass Constructor` in your output). Therefore, there are 5 instances of `TestClass` which get destroyed.

**Note:** Your `Singleton` class is not really a singleton. To follow the singleton pattern correctly, you should disallow copying and assigning by declaring the (copy) constructors and destructors as `private`:

```
template <typename Type>
class Singleton {
public:
  static Type& GetInstance() {
    static Type instance;
    return instance;
  }
private:
  Singleton() {}
  ~Singleton() {}

  // Dont forget to declare these two. You want to make sure they
  // are unaccessable otherwise you may accidently get copies of
  // your singleton appearing.
  Singleton(const Singleton&);                // Don't Implement
  Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);     // Don't implement
};
```

There are some helpful discussions about [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

If C++11 is available, it's better to use

```
private:
  Singleton() = default;
  ~Singleton() = default;

  Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
  Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
```

This ensures that nobody, not even the class itself, can call the copy or copy assignment functions.

Comment: If C++11 is available it's better to replace those `; // Don't Implement` with `= delete;`. This ensures that nobody, not even the class itself, can call the copy or copy assignment functions. And you can use `= default;` instead of empty braces for the private constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 1):

So having a Singleton template class is overkill and not necessary.  Singleton is a design pattern, not a type.

For each class T you want to make a singleton, simply:

1. add the `instance` static function
2. make private the default constructor (and only call it in `instance` method)
3. delete the copy constructor

This will prevent more than one instance of type T from being created.

Try the following:

```
class TestClass {
public:

  // 1
  static TestClass& instance() { static TestClass x; return x; }

private:

  // 2
  TestClass() {
    std::cout << "TestClass Constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  // 3
  TestClass(const TestClass&) = delete;

  ~TestClass() {
    std::cout << "   TestClass Destructor" << std::endl;
  }
};

void runSingletonTest() {
  TestClass& tc = TestClass::instance();
  TestClass& tc2 = TestClass::instance();
  TestClass& tc3 = TestClass::instance();
  TestClass& tc4 = TestClass::instance();
}
```

Now you have 4 references to the same object, and you can't accidentally create a second TestClass.

Answer (score 0):

The "static Type instance" in your template is creating another instance.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Meyer´s singleton pattern  with mistake.

getInstance should have form:

```
Singleton & GetInstance() {
   static Singleton instance;
   return instance;
}
```

Comment: It will take a good bit more than this fix. There is no restriction against creating copies of `TestClass`.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working you should:

1. Make `Singleton`'s constructor, copy constructor and assignment operator protected (not private).
2. Derive your TestClass from Singleton template.

   class TestClass : public Singleton
   {
       ...
   };

Try and let me know if it works for you ;)